# How to access this bidimensional array in another function?

Tags: c, arrays, function

I have these two functions:

```
void insert(void) //inserts values in the bidimensional array
{
    int array[d][d]; // d is the value given by the user elsewhere
    int a = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < d; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < d; j++){
            array[i][j] = (d*d) - a;
            a++;
        }
    }
}

void show(void) //prints the values
{
    for (int i = 0; i < d; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < d; j++){
            printf("%d", array[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

My problem is that the show() function prints only zeros (0), but these are not the right values.

I know that the values are inserted right, because when I put the printf("%d", array[i][j]); inside the loop of the insert() function, it prints normally. So my guess is that the  show() function does not access the values of the array because it is declared in another function.

So I tried to make that array global writing it outside the function, but it gave me the error: "variable length array declaration not allowed at file scope", so I tried putting it inside main(), before the calls of the two functions above, but I got another error: "unused variable 'array'".

So can anyone help me figure out how to access that array in the show() function?

P.S. I want that two functions: one to get and other to show the numbers, I do not want a single function.

Comment: You have many undefined variables! Where did you defined d or v?

Comment: Sorry, they are the same variables actually, I tried to simplify and ended up forggeting the loop part. But it is already corrected, I changed the v for d. The d is a value given by the user in other part of the code, this is only the part that I am having trouble with.

Comment: there is no `array` declared in `show`. Do you have a global variable with the same name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void *Array = NULL;
int D;

void insert(void){
    int (*array)[D] = Array;
    int a = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < D; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < D; j++){
            array[i][j] = (D*D) - a;
            a++;
        }
    }
}

void show(void){
    int (*array)[D] = Array;
    for (int i = 0; i < D; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < D; j++){
            printf("%3d ", array[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main(void){
    D = 5;
    Array = malloc(sizeof(int [D][D]));
    insert();
    show();
    free(Array);

    return 0;
}
```

---

or

```
int main(void){
    D = 5;
    int array[D][D];
    Array = array;
    insert();
    show();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

You can pass your array as a pointer!

```
#include <stdio.h>


void insert(int d, int array[][d]) {

    int a = 0, i , j;

    for (i = 0; i < d; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < d; j++) {
            array[i][j] = (d*d) - a;
            a++;
        }
    }
}

void show(int d, int array[][d]) {

    int i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < d; i++ ){
        for (j = 0; j < d; j++)
            printf(" %3d ", array[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
}


int main() {

    int d = 5; //user input
    int array[d][d]; //array

    insert(d, array);
    show(d, array);


    return 0;

}
```

Comment: normally, one would write show(int d, int array[][d]) or show(int d, int **array).

Comment: @booboo oh Omg! Yes your right! changed it to `show(int d, int array[][d])`

Comment: @booboo `int **array` is different to `int array[][d]` and does not work

Answer (score -3):

Try with pointer, pass the array as reference. Given that you know what is the value for d

```
void show(int* arRef, int d) //prints the values, here pass d as length of array. 
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < d; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j < d; j++){
                printf("%d", &arRef[i][j]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Indexing with two sets of brackets like that won't work with `int *`.